# What is this clear sticky mucus coming from my leopard gecko's vent?

Tags: leopard-geckos, geckos, excretions

> There is a clear sticky mucus coming out of my male gecko's vent. It looks a bit like what you see on eggs in females. What is this? Is it sperm? A sign he's constipated?

(Question taken from a Facebook group and reposted here to see if anyone can help.)